# passing byte[] from C# to sql table via XML

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, binary, arrays

I Have basically calculated SHA512 hash and I get it in byte[], all I want to do is to store it in my DB, the current infrastructure is such that i need to create a XML of my data and this XML gets passed to a SP which inserts the data. So the flow becomes

byte[] -> string (using BitConverter) -> XML -> binary(64)(using OPENXML)

I think this can be improved, but unfortunately I cannot change the infrastructure, so the XML has to be in between, also what happens is that the XML data I had -

1031B4BFC79B4E6357FE271FF2313D37A90E29FCAAEC850E5C4044547C1184AE

becomes

0x31003000330031004200340042004600430037003900420034004500360033003500370046004500320037003100460046003200330031003300440033003700

in the db

This does not look like the binary form of original data. Any explanation on whats happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string that comes out looks like little-Endian Unicode of the original hex string.

I.e., 0x3100 for '1', 0x3000 for '0', 0x3300 for '3', 0x3100 for '1', 0x4200 for 'B', etc.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I wouldn't use BitConverter for such a purpose.

use

```
Convert.FromBase64String(string s);
```

and

```
Convert.ToBase64String(byte[] inArray);
```

instead.

if you want to know further information on Base64 and its structure, take a look to
[Base64 On Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

and if this does not help, please provide some more information and code about your problem

Comment: Thanks, I will remember that, but why dont we have Convert.ToBase128String, it should be just about using twice as many symbols and we have lots. I wonder what would be the most compact form

Comment: base 64 is useful when you want to transmit byte arrays using a text-based system such as http protocol, or just an xml. base 64 maps every 6 bit to a 8 bit representation. as you can see in the referenced link, there are 64 characters which are safe to transmit in a text-based media, but I don't believe that there are 128 ones of them. maybe that is why we don't have base 128. and about the compression, your size will grow with a ratio of 8/6 (or 4/3) when you convert it to base 64. I hope I helped

Answer (score 1):

when you  encode array of  bytes to base 64 its string representation of orginal data
so you can  use Convert.FromBase64String(fieldvalue)
to getting orginal byte data